# Executing chdir before starting systemd service

Tags: systemd

#### Question: Can I kick off a process with systemd and assign that process a working directory of my choosing?

I have a service that I want to start with `systemd`. When that service is being started, I want to be able to assign it a current working directory. I know how to do this if I was using `init`, but I'm having trouble with `systemd`.

Here's what I've been trying to get working.

#### My Service

I created a simple utility ("listdir"), written in Python, and placed in `/opt/bin/listdir`:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python

import os

print 'Current working directory: %s' % (os.getcwd())
```

#### My Configuration File

I then created a `listdir.service` file for `systemd` and placed it here: `/lib/systemd/system/listdir.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test of listing CWD.

[Service]
ExecStartPre=chdir /usr/local
ExecStart=/opt/bin/listdir
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### Problem

When I run `systemctl start listdir` my system log records the root directory ("/") as the current working directory. Of course, I expected `/usr/local` as the current directory, since I thought `ExecStartPre` would change directories before starting the process.

Obviously, I'm imagining that `systemd` would work something like a shell script (even though I know it isn't a shell script). Can someone give me an idea of what I should be doing? Is it even possible to set a working directory using `systemd`? Thanks!

---

*Edit:* My system log is reporting an error. (I just noticed.)

```
Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: chdir /usr/local
```

So, `chdir` is a shell command, and not an executable itself. Okay. But is there still some way for me to change directories using `systemd`?

Answer (score 325, accepted):

On systemd >= 227 you should be able to use:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local
```

to get your script to execute there.

([DOCS](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Options))

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly it. I'm sorry I didn't come across that on my own. (I can accept your answer in 8 minutes.)

Comment: How did you find this? It's not mentioned anywhere in [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)!

Comment: @jameshfisher it's in [this part of the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)

Comment: @EricRenouf aha, they should just duplicate those shared options in the service documentation

Comment: So just for clarity, would this go in the `[Service]` section?

Comment: Yup, realized my mistake and changed it, sorry for the ninja-edit! But yes, thanks, `[Service]` is the correct section.

Comment: CentOS 7 seems to be using 219, do you know if this feature was backported?

Comment: Answering myself, it worked on latest CentOS 7, despite of the version.

Comment: [systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) says "The execution specific configuration options are configured in the `[Service]`, `[Socket]`, `[Mount]`, or `[Swap]` sections, depending on the unit type.", in addition to options specific to `[Service]` section mentioned [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Options).