# I can't specify a directory when creating a service on Beaglebone

Tags: systemd, python, services, beagleboneblack

I don't know where to post this question because it's half a programming question and half a Linux question, so forgive me.

I'm working on a project using Beaglebone Black and I need to execute a very complex python script automatically after the boot, so I followed this tutorial:

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854705/executing-a-script-on-startup-using-beaglebone-black)

which worked, but the script is executed in the `/` directory and not in the correct directory, which is `/root/pyfingerprint/examples/`, so when the program tries to execute things in the `examples` directory it can't find them.

I tried adding a complete path for every line of code which required it and it worked for some parts of the project but it's not enough for cv2 and other libraries.

I tried to solve the problem simply adding `os.system("cd /root/pyfingerprint/examples/")` at the beginning of the python script but when the program execute on boot it says that the current directory is still `/`

The program works perfectly when executed manually but not on boot time.

Is there a way to set the working directory of the service to automatically execute it in the right directory?

Comment: You should `cd` in shell before execute main python script, not `cd` inside the python script. You should show us how you execute your main python script if you need further assist.

Comment: I'm not an expert on creating services, I just need to edit my .sh script and that's it or I need to do some other operations after that?

Comment: You need to show us the code inside shell script(.sh) which run the python script(s). Is there any issue if you put `cd /root/pyfingerprint/examples/;` inside shell script before run the python script(s)?

Comment: Or you may want to do this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200657/64403

Comment: It worked! i added cd /root/pyfingerprint/examples/ before launching the script. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note,  `os.system()` has no effect as it creates a new process in which to do the operation. Instead use `os.chdir('/....')`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Fruit the solution is to add `cd [dir]` in the .sh script to launch the program. in my case the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /root/pyfingerprint/examples/
python3 main.py
```